# Как ограничить пространство ссылке средствами css?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать возможность нажатия на ссылку вне картинки логотипа? На данный момент перейти по ссылке можно в любом месте по бокам логотипа.

```
<a href="index.html" class="a_logo">
   <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
</a>
```

```
.logo {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.a_logo{
    
}
```

Comment: Вот самые нужные и интересные стили на скриншоте обрезаны. Поэтому вместо неудобных для понимания картиннок лучше приведите [mcve] нормальным текстовым кодом

Comment: добавил код из css

Comment: В `.logo` добавляется пространство через margin и padding, вот они и кликаются — значит для решения проблемы уберите margin и padding из него, а если нужно сохранить пространство, значит добавьте margin например для ссылки или какого-нибудь другого внешнего контейнера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container">
  <a href="https://picsum.photos/" class="a_logo">
    <img class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое все работает